# The concept of attractivnes

Tags: god, fall

I want to ask why would God create such concept as attractivness if He does not look at someone’s looks? 1 Samuel 16:7 ”for man looks at the outward appearance, but the LORD looks at the heart.” Study after study shows that there is objective beauty which is symmetry and anything that has symmetry is considered pretty or more prettier than anything else. Also there are genes that are better and stronger and people with such genes tend to look pretty (symmetrical), think more positive, be very healthy and accomplish a lot of things. Weaker genes give the opposite and someone with such genes struggles. It seems like before the fall people were very symmetrical and had stronger genes but after the fall the degradation happened. Also Salomon’s song is clear that people are designed to be attracted also to looks. I just feel kid of down because if God does not care about looks then why did He bother to do objective attraction like symmetry, better genes etc. I always thought that all the features that we have have are considered unattractive were just made that way by us because after the fall we choose what is pretty and what is not and if we did not fall we would not care but studies show something completely different and we are creatures attracted to symmetry which gives pretty features and in turn good genes because symmetry comes from them. Children are the best example, they tend to go to prettier symmetrical things, animals and people. What do you think?

Comment: You are mixing two distinct ideas.  Attractiveness concerns physical beauty.  The matter that God examines in the judgement is moral uprightness which has nothing to do with physical beauty.

Comment: @Lucy Red your question will probably be closed as off-topic. You might be able to rescue it by editing the title so that it asks an actual question about a specific biblical verse. Also rework the rest of the question so that you are asking about biblical verses rather than a general topic. Otherwise you might try asking it on Christianity.SE... In the meantime please check the Tour and the Help sections to get guidance on asking questions.